# Getting identifier error in react application

Tags: reactjs

I am creating react application to fetch data from youtube API and for that, I am using a method in the component but I am getting an error which says "[js] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected." when I declare that method. Can anyone help to solve that error?

code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    videos: []
  };

  YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: "surfboards" }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

error:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call the function `YTSearch`, with that object and function as the parameters. What was your intention?

Comment: I am trying to set up API call to youtube. **import YTSearch from "youtube-api-search"; **

Comment: Okay the problem was that you can't call functions inside a class body like that.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to put the function call in a lifecycle method:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: "surfboards" }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

read more about react lifecycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)